# Angular 6: Custom pipe returns NaN if data is from a service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating a custom pipe that translates a given number into days and hours. The HTML that goes into it looks something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let unit of units">
   <p>Remaining Life</p>
   <h2>{{ unit.daysRemaining | timeRemaining }}</h2>
</div>
```

Originally, I had the `unit` object exist inside the component. The pipe correctly translated the number, [as seen in this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axdfge).

However, I wanted to use a service to load it. When I did so, the values became `undefined` (which I've set up to show as 0 in the pipe). [This StackBlitz shows the result.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axdfge-ozle8c)

What's the difference between the two? Why does an `undefined` value appear when loading my data from a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

In your service you have created an object array, and every object holds `hoursRemaining` property, but in your `app.component.html` your are trying to access `daysRemaining` property, which is undefined because it is not declared in the objects.

**Solution:**

Change access `hoursRemaining` in the `app.component.html`.

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div>
    <div>Custom Pipe:</div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let unit of units">{{ unit.hoursRemaining | daysRemaining }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Fixed example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axdfge-bx4t4x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

You've got:

```
<li *ngFor="let unit of units">{{ unit.daysRemaining | daysRemaining }}</li>
```

but should be:

```
<li *ngFor="let unit of units">{{ unit.hoursRemaining | daysRemaining }}</li>
```

in the second stackblitz in app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Just use `hoursRemaining` instead of `daysRemaining` in the template and it'll work

**Tip**

`<li *ngFor="let unit of units">{{ unit | json }}</li>` was an easy way to debug - you can see what's being passed to your pipe.

Answer (score 0):

With this changes your code work correctly:

```
<li *ngFor="let unit of units">{{ unit.hoursRemaining | daysRemaining }}</li>
```